# How to properly Join a table to show category, subcategory and product ID

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join

I'm new to coding and I been trying to figure out how to properly Join a table. I been reading about it but for some reason having a little trouble wrapping my head around it.

I set up a localhost and have been messing around with PHP and MySQL. I been trying to create categories and subcategories in the same table. I have a table with the following rows.

> ```
> Table name: categories
>  id
> main_cat
> parent_id
> sub_cat_name
> ```

I been trying to make a table that would display each subcategory with its corresponding main category and parent id. I been doing research online and came across JOIN tables. Far I have been able to display the subcategory with its corresponding main category but can not display the parent id. The parent id returns `null`. Below is my code. Can anyone explain to be why this isn't work and if this is the best way of displaying the data.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Subcategory Name</th>
        <th>Main Category</th>
        <th>Parent ID</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php

        // connect to database
        include 'config/config.php';
        include 'config/opendb.php';

        $sql='SELECT t1.main_cat_name, t2.sub_cat_name, t3.parent_id FROM categories t1
        LEFT JOIN categories t2 ON t2.parent_id = t1.main_cat_id
        LEFT JOIN categories t3 ON t2.main_cat_id = t3.parent_id
        WHERE t2.sub_cat_name IS NOT NULL;';
        $rs=$conn->query($sql);

        $rs->data_seek(0);
        while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
        {

            $mainCatName = $row['main_cat_name'];
            $subCatName  = $row['sub_cat_name'];

            echo"<tr>
            <td>$subCatName</td>
            <td>$mainCatName</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>";
        }
        $conn->close();
    ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question i come to know you want these:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Subcategory Name</th>
    <th>Main Category</th>
    <th>Parent ID</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

    // connect to database
    include 'config/config.php';
    include 'config/opendb.php';

    $sql='SELECT main_cat AS `main_cat_name`, sub_cat_name AS `sub_cat_name`, parent_id FROM categories WHERE sub_cat_name IS NOT NULL;';
    $rs=$conn->query($sql);

    $rs->data_seek(0);
    while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
    {          

        echo"<tr>
        <td>$row['main_cat_name']</td>
        <td>$row['sub_cat_name']</td>
        <td>$row['parent_id']</td>
    </tr>";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: My query is wrong because it is still returning the main_cat_name empty. I been trying different search query's but either main_cat_name or sub_cat_name return empty.